# Exchange 2010 Hybrid Configuration Wizard Web Services External Url

Tags: exchange-2010, migration, microsoft-office-365

I have an on-premise Exchange 2010 that I'm trying to configure for Hybrid migration.

When I run the Hybrid Configuration Wizard from the EMC, it seems to complete okay but I get a warning at the end:

> Warning:
>   The Client Access Server APOLLO does not have a Certificate that contains the On-premises Web Services External Url domain (email.mydomain.com) in the certificate Subject or Alternate Names

What I can't work out is where it's getting that domain name from. The Exchange server is set up a UC certificate that has a bunch of SANs on it:

- mail.mydomain.com
- www.mail.mydomain.com
- apollo.mydomain.com
- autodiscover.mydomain.com
- dialin.mydomain.com
- lync.mydomain.com
- meet.mydomain.com
- webmail.mydomain.com
- www.mail.mydomain.com

Where is the wizard looking for that domain name, so I can change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing its the externalURL of your EWS virtual directory. Try running the following command in the Exchange Management Shell:

```
Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | Select Name,*url
```

Comment: Aha, got it - had to run the "Configure External Client Access Domain" command from the EMC under Server Config/Client Access.